# Firebase deploy in Github Actions gives Authorization failed error

Tags: firebase, github-actions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to automate the deployment of a react app to firebase with github actions but i'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Autorization failed. This account is missing the following required permissions on project ***
 firebase.projects.get
 firebasehosting.sites.update
```

I have multiple sites and when I try to deploy manually using `firebase deploy --only hosting:MY_SITE_NAME` it's working correctly. I have two jobs in my workflow. The build job passes but the deploy one fails. Here's my workflow file:

```
name: Build and Deploy to Firebase
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: yarn install
      - name: Build
        run: yarn build
      - name: Archive Production Artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
          path: build
  deploy:
    name: Deploy
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Download Artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@master
        with:
          name: build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting:MY_SITE_NAME
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

Comment: How exactly did you configure the account that you want to use for deployment with the Firebase CLI?

Comment: You mean locally? I ran the commands from firebase-tools. firebase login, then firebase init. Then I selected the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the Firebase CLI in a CI/CD environment such as GitHub Action, you'll have to provide a way for the CLI to know the account credentials it should use.  When you run locally, it can get the credentials from your interaction with `firebase login`.  But when you run elsewhere, there is no UI to prompt you.

You will have to [follow the instructions in the documentation on integrating with CI/CD system](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#cli-ci-systems), and provide a token for the account that should be used to authorize the deployment.

Comment: Yes, I did that too. Sorry I forgot to mention it. I added the token in Github as a secret. i'm using it here `FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}`

Comment: The error message is telling you that the account represented by that token simply doesn't have the required permissions. What have you done to ensure that it has permission?

Comment: You were right. I'm so silly. When I ran the `firebase login:ci` command, firebase was opening a chrome tab from the wrong account Chrome window (I had two different sessions opened) and I didn't even see it when I clicking to log in... Anyway thanks a lot for your help mate!

Comment: `firebase login:ci` is going to be deprecated soon. How to authenticate using other methods?