# How to deploy flutter to firebase through github actions using workload identity federation

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, workload-identity

When deploying flutter to firebase from local machine I do following and it works:

```
flutter build web
firebase deploy
```

When trying to deploy from GHA , my yaml file looks like this

```
test_deploy_to_dev:
    name: deploy
    needs:
      - label_check
    permissions:
      contents: read
      id-token: write

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - id: auth
        name: 'Authenticate to Google Cloud'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v1'
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: 'projects/1111111/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/abc/providers/xyz'
          service_account: 'firebase-deploy-flutter@project123.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

      - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          channel: 'stable'
          cache: true
      - name: Run flutter pub get
        run: flutter pub get
      - name: Enable flutter web
        run: flutter config --enable-web
      - name: Build Web App
        run: flutter build web
      - name: deploy flutter to firestore
        run: |
          npm install -g firebase-tools
          firebase init
          firebase deploy
```

Google auth part works.
In GHA, I get error - `Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase deploy in Github Actions gives Authorization failed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60380374/firebase-deploy-in-github-actions-gives-authorization-failed-error)

Comment: No. Method used for authentication in that link you provided is old and soon going to be deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error `Failed to authenticate, have you run firebase login?` happens because workload identity is not setup correctly.

Dont follow [Official doc](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/enabling-keyless-authentication-from-github-actions). It has a small error.

Instead follow [Github doc](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth). It shows how to create WIF through CLI and provides a working template to authorize GHA through WIF.

- Enable "Firebase Management API" in your GCP project
- Firebase project and gcp project are 2 different things. I was using sv_account from a gcp project to deploy into a different firebase project. Hence all those auth errors shown below.
- sv_account needs following permissions:

  - Firebase Hosting Admin
  - Service Account User
- In GHA template provided in Github doc link above: in workload_identity_provider key:

  - `workload_identity_provider: 'projects/<gcp-project-id>/locations/global/workloadIdentityPools/<my-pool-id>/providers/<provider-id>'`
  - use pool_id and provider_id. Dont use pool_name and provider_name
  - gcp_project_id (all int) is different from project_id.